# Symfony2 toString() method with multiple variables

Tags: php, symfony, tostring, entities

I've built an entitiy, which has associations with more than one other table for data, which will be used to populate a "**dropdown**" element on a form.

However, when I try to open the page, it says I've got a **`toString()`** error. I've handled this before with a single entity relationship, but I'm clueless how to handle it on a multiple relationship system.

### Here is my code:

```
class Articles
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="datetime", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $datetime;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ArticlesCategory", inversedBy="articles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="path", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $path;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ArticlesAuthor", inversedBy="articles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $author;   

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Matches", inversedBy="articles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="match_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $match; 

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->??????????;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I can return an array, or have to somehow define it elsewhere. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `__toString` simply must return a **string**. Any arbitrary **string**.

Comment: Doesn't this in effect make it useless then? Isn't the point of toString() to format what it returns so that form elements can utilize it?

Comment: It does not make it useless. `__toString()` as it follows from the name converts an arbitrary object that has defined it into a string. If you want to return array - create `toArray()` method and use it.

Comment: So I could return "12345" and it would still work? I must not be getting what you're meaning by arbitrary.

Comment: You may return **any string**. Like **any string**. As soon as `"12345"` is a string - it will work.

Comment: `return $this->title;` would be nice for your entity

Comment: Even `return 'Item with ID: ' . $this->id;` will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`__toString()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) is one of PHP's magic methods:

> __toString() allows a class to decide how it will react when it is treated like a string. For example, what echo $obj; will print. This method must return a string, as otherwise a fatal E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR level error is emitted.

It has little to do with Symfony. I'm guessing you use one of the [doctrine entity field types](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html).

By default, the entity field type will cast an object to string and PHP will try to call the `__toString()` method on it. You can either provide the `__toString()` method, or explicitly set the method that should be called instead (see [the property](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#property) docs).

Either way, you need to return a string, so it could be displayed in the dropdown.

It can be any string:

```php
public function __toString()
{
    return 'any string';
}
```

You could use one of the fields:

```php
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->title;
}
```

Or generate more complex strings, even use your object's collaborators:

```php
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->title . ' (' . $this->category->getName() . ')';
}
```

**Make sure to check which object is actually being cast to string.** It might be you're adding the method in a wrong class.